# is it possible to implement dynamic class weights in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

keras supports the `class_weights` feature to allow giving different classes different weights - for example for when the number of samples is imbalanced

I want to do something similar, but to use dynamic weights, based on the class imbalance in each batch.

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Make a manual loop for epochs and batches, use the method `train_on_batch`, which also accepts `class_weight`:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batchX,batchY in batches: #adapt this loop to your way of creating/getting batches

        weights = calculateOrGetTheWeights(batch)
        model.train_on_batch(batchX,batchY,...,class_weight=weights)
```

**Option 2:**

Create a custom loss. May be more tricky and depends on the data format, the number of classes, the type of loss function, etc.

Assuming 2D data (samples, classes) and a multiclass problem:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    classes = K.argmax(yTrue)
    classCount = K.sum(yTrue,axis=0)

    loss = K.some_loss_function(yTrue,yPred)

    return loss / K.gather(classCount, classes)
```

Assuming a binary classification (1 class only) with 1D or 2D data:

```
import keras.backend as K

def binaryCustomLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    positives = yTrue
    negatives = 1 - yTrue

    positiveRatio = K.mean(positives)
    negativeRatio = 1 - positiveRatio #or K.mean(negatives)

    weights = (positives / positiveRatio) + (negatives / negativeRatio)

    #you may need K.squeeze(weights) here

    return weights * K.some_loss_function(yTrue,yPred)
```

Warning: both loss functions will return Nan (or infinity) if any class count is zero.

Comment: thanks, I like the custom loss function.
How would it be for a binary classification problem?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to, instead of using `class_weight`, use samples weights

If you want your sample weight to be dynamic you'll need to use `fit_generator` instead of `fit`, so you can change the weights on the run

So in pseudo code:

```
def gen(x, y):
    while True:
        for x_batch, y_batch in make_batches(x, y):
            weights = make_weights(y_batch)
            yield x_batch, y_batch, weights
model.fit_generator(gen(x_train, y_train))
```

In this code, `make_weights` should return an array with the same length as `y_batch`. Each element is a weight to be applied to the respective sample

If you're unsure about the behavior of `class_weight` and sample weights being the same, [notice](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L483) how keras standardizes class weights.

So class weights are actually translated to sample weights in the end :)